# Return Type Boolean, Failure to Print Value

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, return

I am attempting to compile a program that searches an array for a certain element, `int target`. It needs to be a `public static boolean` method, yet the code I have, as constituted, fails to print a return value. Why is this? Have I not accounted for all cases? Thanks for any input, I'm sure it must be something small that I am overlooking.

Code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  int[] array = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 19, 21, -1, -45, 0};
  int target = 2; 
 }

 public static boolean linearSearch(int[] array, int target)
 {
   boolean linearSearch = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ 
     if(array[i] == target){
     linearSearch = true; 
     }
     else{
       linearSearch = false;
     }
   }
   return linearSearch;  
 }
}
```

Also, somewhat besides the point, can this be coded as the following instead?

```
public class ArrayUtilities
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  int[] array = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 19, 21, -1, -45, 0};
  int target = 2; 
}

 public static boolean linearSearch(int[] array, int target)
 {
   boolean linearSearch = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ 
     if(array[i] == target){
       linearSearch = true; 
     }
   return linearSearch;  
 }
}
```

Comment: You defined but did not call `linearSearch`.

Comment: ... you never call the method.

Comment: `Also, somewhat besides the point, can this be coded as the following instead?` Did you compile that and run it and see the result?

Comment: Compiling a code doesn't mean running it. Also, you need to invoke a method to execute it.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick and helpful responses. I guess I was under the misconception that return (value); actually would print true or false. Running the second bit of code does not print anything, likely because of what I just mentioned When you refer to calling a method, I do that from my main, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides from not calling the `linearSearch` function in your `main` method, your first version of `linearSearch` could return `false` even if the item exists.

Your second version is fine but it can also be improved by returning from the function if an item is found like:

```
 public static boolean linearSearch(int[] array, int target)
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ 
     if(array[i] == target){
        return true;
   }
   return false;  
 }
}
```

Also you need to call it in your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  int[] array = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 19, 21, -1, -45, 0};
  int target = 2; 
  if(linearSearch(array,target)) {
      System.out.print("found");
  }
}
```

Problem with your first version is that an item could be found in, lets say , second iteration of the `for` loop, your bool `linearSearch` would be set to `true`, but if that item doesn't exist at the end of your array, you will get `false` result, because the `else` part would set to to `false` for all the other elements in array.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't printing anything. In Java execution starts from `public static void main(String[])` method and it usually ends there. In your case this method initializes some variables and exits. You need to call `linearSearch(array, target)`, store it in a variable and then print (or pass return value to print function), i.e. `System.out.println(linearSearch(array, target));`.

The second chunk of code should work well. The first one, however, will result in wrong output. Consider array `1, 2, 3` and target `2`. Loop will iterate through the array, find `2`, set `linearSearch` to `true`, then go to `3` and set `linearSearch` to `false`. That's not what you want. After an element is found, it cannot be unfound.

Comment: A clear and informative answer, and written in a basic cs diction that I can understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could return the true or false value.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 19, 21, -1, -45, 0};
    int target = 2;
    System.out.println(linearSearch(array, target));
}
public static boolean linearSearch(int[] array, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        if (array[i] == target) 
            return true;
    return false;
}
```